# Perl ssl client auth using certificate

Tags: perl

I'm having trouble getting the following code to work and at a point where I am stuck. I am trying to perform client side authentication using a certificate during a POST request. I'm only interested in sending the client cert to the server and don't really need to check the server certificate.

Here is the cUrl command that trying to replicate:

curl --cacert caCertificate.pem --cert clientCerticate.pem -d "string" https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/postRf


I keep getting the following error in my Perl script:
ssl handshake failure


I guess I have two questions: what should I be pointing to for CRT7 AND KEY8 variables? and is this the best way to send a POST request using client cert authentication?

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SSLeay qw(post_https);


my $$hostIp = "xx.xx.xx.xx" 
my $hostPort = "8443" 
my $postCommand = "/postRf/string";
my $http_method = 'plain/text';
my $path_to_crt7 = 'pathToCert.pem';
my $path_to_key8 = 'pathToKey.pem';

my ($page, $response, %reply_headers) =
        post_https($hostIp, $hostPort, $postCommand, '',
        $http_method, $path_to_crt7, $path_to_key8
);

print $page . "\n";
print $response . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

See [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) and [IO::Socket::SSL](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL).

```
use strictures;
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
require LWP::Protocol::https;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts(
    SSL_ca_file   => 'caCertificate.pem',
    SSL_cert_file => 'clientCerticate.pem',
);
$ua->post(
    'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/postRf',
    Content => 'string',
);
```

I haven't tested this code.